# JavaScript parse JSON

Tags: javascript, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to parse JSON in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4935632)

I have this [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) string:

```
[{"title": "Title1"}, {"title": "Title2"}]
```

How can I parse it, so that I can get each title?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
var string = '[{"title":"Title1"},{"title":"Title2"}]';

var array = JSON.parse(string);
array.forEach(function(object) {
  console.log(object.title);
});
```

Note that `JSON.parse` [isn't available in all browsers](http://caniuse.com/json); [use JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) where necessary.

The same goes for ES5 `Array#forEach`, of course. This is just an example.

If you're using jQuery, you could use `$.each` to iterate over the array instead. jQuery has a [`jQuery.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method, too.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using jQuery just do:

```
var myArray = jQuery.parseJSON('[{"title":"Title1"},{"title":"Title2"}]');
```

Answer (score 3):

If that's directly in your JS then it works out of the box:

```
var obj = [{"title":"Title1"},{"title":"Title2"}];
alert(obj[0].title); // "Title1";
```

If it's received via AJAX:

```
// obj contains the data
if( typeof JSON != "undefined") obj = JSON.parse(obj);
else obj = eval("("+obj+")");
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a for loop, perhaps? :o

```
for(var i = 0; i < jsonVar.length; i++) {
   alert(jsonVar[i].title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.parse()`.

Not all browsers have support for that method, so you can use Douglas Crockford's polyfill.
Here: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

EDIT:
Here's the browser support stats for it:
http://www.caniuse.com/#search=JSON

Answer (score 0):

With [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) ([json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) will provide a version of that for older browsers).

Comment: Haven't you heard? [JSON 3](http://bestiejs.github.com/json3/) is the new `json2.js`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example, using jQuery:

```
var jsonObj = $.parseJSON('[{"title": "Title1"}, {"title": "Title2"}]');
var title1 = jsonObj[0].title; //Title1
var title2 = jsonObj[1].title; //Title1
```

​You can see a demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/pBb4j/